# Performance Gain Through GIST Index for Point in Polygon Query

Tags: postgis, sql, point-in-polygon, optimization

I have two tables: locations(id,region_id,the_geom) and regions(id,the_geom). For each location point I want to determine the region it is located in:

```
UPDATE locations SET region_id = 
 (SELECT id FROM regions 
  WHERE ST_Within(locations.the_geom,regions.the_geom)
 );
```

Does it make sense to build a GIST index on the location points? I'll build an index on the region polygons but I'm unsure about the points. Would it speed up the query?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Short answer:** No. With this type of UPDATE query, we are updating each row in `locations` ("Seq Scan"), and the GiST index on `the_geom` in `regions` is sufficient in helping limit rows for the `ST_Within` condition to pair-up the right row from `regions`.

---

**Longer answer:** The magic to figuring this out is to compare what you get from [explain query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html). From pgAdmin III, there is an "Explain query" button at the top of a query editor, or from pgsql, just prefix your query with "explain":

```
postgis=# explain UPDATE locations SET region_id =
postgis-#  (SELECT id FROM regions
postgis(#   WHERE ST_Within(locations.the_geom, regions.the_geom)
postgis(#  );
                                         QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..8755.54 rows=1000 width=110)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Index Scan using regions_gist_the_geom on regions  (cost=0.00..8.52 rows=1 width=4)
           Index Cond: ($0 && the_geom)
           Filter: _st_within($0, the_geom)
(5 rows)
```

You don't need to understand everything that is coughed up here. The key thing to see here is in the inner-most part (SubPlan 1) it indicates "Index" (= uses an index, which could speed things up considerably), and not "Seq Scan" (= sequence scan, i.e. checking each row to see if it is within, which can be slower). If you add/delete a GiST index on `locations`, the output of this explain query is exactly the same, so the query performance should be the same.

However, if you do something silly, and remove your GiST index from `regions`, you see a different query plan from the same query as above:

```
                             QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on locations  (cost=0.00..74288.00 rows=1000 width=110)
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Seq Scan on regions  (cost=0.00..74.05 rows=1 width=4)
           Filter: (($0 && the_geom) AND _st_within($0, the_geom))
(4 rows)
```

The important thing to see between the two explain queries is the maximum cost estimates .. contrast 74.05 here to 8.52 before, so you'd expect this query to be slower.