# Acquiring ArcGIS-like speed in Postgis

Tags: postgis, sql, algorithm, spatial-index

I have been using Postgis 2.0 for 3/4 of a year now and while I really enjoy using it, excessive query processing time has rendered it basically unusable for my use case.

I tend to do heavy geoprocessing on municipal datasets which often have hundreds of thousands of multipolygons. These multipolygons are sometimes shaped very irregularly and can vary from 4 points to 78,000 points per multipolygon.

For example, when I intersect  a parcel dataset with 329,152 multipolygons with a jurisdiction dataset containing 525 multipolygons,  I get the following stats for total time consumed:

```
ArcGIS 10.0 (on same host with windows 7 OS): 3 minutes
Postgis:56 minutes (not including geometry pre-processing queries)
```

In other words, **it requires 1500% more time to do this intersection in Postgis than in ArcGIS** --and this is one of my more simple queries!

One of the reasons ArcGIS supposedly runs faster is due to better indexes. Some programmers [recently figured out how these indexes work](https://github.com/drwelby/hasbeen) and I am wondering if anyone knows how to build these indexes in Postgis (or build tables that would mimic the indexes). Perhaps this would solve most of the speed issues in Postgis. I can only hope there must be some way, especially since ArcGIS can only use 4 GB of RAM while I could use up to 4 times that for my postgis server!

Of course there are many reasons postgis can run slowly, so I will provide a detailed version of my system specs:

```
Machine: Dell XPS 8300 
Processor: i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40 GHz 3.40 GHz 
Memory: Total Memory 16.0 GB (10.0 GB on virtual machine)

Platform: Ubuntu Server 12.04 Virtual Box VM

Potgres Version: 9.1.4
Postgis Version: POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.1, released 2012/05/15" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER
```

I also detail the [entire installation process that I used to set up postgis including the creation of the VM itself](http://invalidtopology.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/creating-a-fully-functional-postgis-2-0-1-server-from-source-on-ubuntu/).

I also increased shared memory from the default 24MB to 6 GB in the conf file and ran the following commands to allow postgres to run:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=7516192768 (I know this setting is deleted every time you restart the OS)
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql restart
```

As far as I can tell this does absolutely nothing noticeable in terms of performance.

Here are links to the data I used for this test:

1. Parcels: [tcad_parcels_06142012.shp.zip](ftp://ftp.ci.austin.tx.us/GIS-Data/planning/temp/tcad_parcels_06142012.shp.zip) from [City of Austin, TX](ftp://ftp.ci.austin.tx.us/GIS-Data/planning/temp/)
2. Jurisdictions: [Jurisdictional Boundaries](ftp://ftp.ci.austin.tx.us/GIS-Data/Regional/jurisdiction/jurisdictions.zip) from [City of Austin, TX](ftp://ftp.ci.austin.tx.us/GIS-Data/Regional/coa_gis.html)

Here are the steps I took to process the data:

ArcGIS

1. Add datasets to ArcMap
2. Set coordinate system to central texas feet (srid 2277)
3. Use intersection tool from dropdown menu

Postgis

Import parcels using:

```
shp2pgsql -c -s 2277 -D -i -I -W UTF-8 "tcad_parcels_06142012.shp" "public"."tcad_parcels_06142012" |psql -d postgis_testing -U postgres -h local_ip -p 5432
```

Import jurisdictions using:

```
shp2pgsql -c -s 2277 -D -i -I -W UTF-8 "jurisdictions.shp" "public"."jurisdictions" |psql -d postgis_testing -U postgres -h local_ip -p 5432
```

Clean invalid geometry in parcels:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS valid_parcels;
CREATE TABLE valid_parcels(
  gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  orig_gid integer,
  geom geometry(multipolygon,2277)
);
CREATE INDEX ON valid_parcels USING gist (geom);
INSERT INTO valid_parcels(orig_gid,geom)
  SELECT 
    gid 
    orig_gid,
    st_multi(st_makevalid(geom)) 
  FROM 
    tcad_parcels_06142012;
CLUSTER valid_parcels USING valid_parcels_geom_idx;
```

Clean invalid geometry in jurisdictions:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS valid_jurisdictions;
CREATE TABLE valid_jurisdictions(
  gid serial PRIMARY KEY,
  orig_gid integer,
  geom geometry(multipolygon,2277)
);
CREATE INDEX ON valid_jurisdictions USING gist (geom);
INSERT INTO valid_jurisdictions(orig_gid,geom)
  SELECT 
    gid 
    orig_gid,
    st_multi(st_makevalid(geom)) 
  FROM 
    jurisdictions;
CLUSTER valid_jurisdictions USING valid_jurisdictions_geom_idx;
```

Run cluster:

```
cluster;
```

Run vacuum analyze:

```
vacuum analyze;
```

Perform intersection on cleaned tables:

```
CREATE TABLE parcel_jurisdictions(
  gid serial primary key,
  parcel_gid integer,
  jurisdiction_gid integer,
  isect_geom geometry(multipolygon,2277)
);
CREATE INDEX ON parcel_jurisdictions using gist (isect_geom);

INSERT INTO parcel_jurisdictions(parcel_gid,jurisdiction_gid,isect_geom)
  SELECT
    a.orig_gid parcel_gid,
    b.orig_gid jurisdiction_gid,
    st_multi(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))
  FROM
    valid_parcels a, valid_jurisdictions b
  WHERE
    st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom);
```

Explain Analyze intersection query:

```
Total runtime: 3446860.731 ms
        Index Cond: (geom && b.geom)
  ->  Index Scan using valid_parcels_geom_idx on valid_parcels a  (cost=0.00..11.66 rows=2 width=1592) (actual time=0.030..4.596 rows=1366 loops=525)
  ->  Seq Scan on valid_jurisdictions b  (cost=0.00..113.25 rows=525 width=22621) (actual time=0.009..0.755 rows=525 loops=1)
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..61428.74 rows=217501 width=24213) (actual time=2.625..3445946.889 rows=329152 loops=1)
  Join Filter: _st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

From everything I have read, my intersection query is efficient and I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong for the query to take 56 minutes on clean geometry!

Comment: It's a common idiom in PostGIS to add a bounding box intersection check to speed things up. Try adding 'AND a.geom && b.geom' to your WHERE clause and see how much of a difference it makes.

Comment: st_intersects() includes a bounding box query before performing any intersection testing in postgis 2.x so unfortunately that won't save any time.

Comment: Can you run you query using EXPLAIN ANALYZE and post the results

Comment: @NathanW  Explain Analyze results are added to post now.

Comment: It is still very difficult to say whaat is happening. Your numbers about the daata sets does not say very much becauase the effort needed depends on how many polygon-polygon combinations that passes the st_intersects filter to get computes by st_intersection.

Comment: you should also be aware that you are running different data sets on postgis vs arcgis since you say that you neex to make them valid to be accepted vy postgis.

Comment: Is it possible to get the data sets to take a look at it?

Comment: @NicklasAvén Yes, I included the links to the exact datasets I used in the post

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Different approach. Knowing that the pain is in ST_Intersection, and that true/false tests are fast, trying to minimize the amount of geometry passing through the intersection might speed things up. For example, parcels that are totally contained in a jurisdiction don't need to be clipped, but ST_Intersection will still probably go to the trouble of building part of the intersection overlay before realizing it doesn't have to generate any new geometry. So this

```
INSERT INTO parcel_jurisdictions(parcel_gid,jurisdiction_gid,isect_geom)
SELECT
  a.orig_gid AS parcel_gid,
  b.orig_gid AS jurisdiction_gid,

  st_multi(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom)) AS geom
FROM
  valid_parcels a, valid_jurisdictions b
WHERE
  st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom) and not st_within(a.geom, b.geom)
UNION ALL
SELECT
  a.orig_gid AS parcel_gid,
  b.orig_gid AS jurisdiction_gid,
  a.geom AS geom
FROM
  valid_parcels a, valid_jurisdictions b
WHERE
  st_within(a.geom, b.geom);
```

Or even terser

```
INSERT INTO parcel_jurisdictions(parcel_gid,jurisdiction_gid,isect_geom)
SELECT
  a.orig_gid AS parcel_gid,
  b.orig_gid AS jurisdiction_gid,
  CASE 
     WHEN ST_Within(a.geom,b.geom) 
     THEN a.geom
     ELSE ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(a.geom,b.geom)) 
  END AS geom
FROM valid_parcels a
JOIN valid_jurisdictions b
ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
```

Might even be faster w/o the UNION.

Comment: Thanks that gets me down to, 3.63 minutes! I would have never thought a union would be faster. This answer is really going to make me rethink the way I do queries from now on.

Comment: This is very cool.  I had a case at work where my st_intersection query was take 30mins+ and now I know how I can avoid that :)

Comment: this question made me learn Postgis! i will sleep well today seeing Postgis run shoulder to shoulder with Arcgis :-)

Comment: One more enhancement from Martin Davis, you could inline the "in or out?" question into the SELECT using a CASE statement and avoid the UNION that way.

Comment: `UNION` eliminates duplicated rows from the two queries, but these two queries cannot have the same row in their result set. So `UNION ALL`, which skips the duplicate check, would be appropriate here. (I don't use `UNION` that much, but I generally find that out of the times I do, I much more frequently use `UNION ALL`.)

Comment: just a comment.. I have a different dataset and a similar query and I do not bother with the "st_within" stuff and get the exact results if I do include it.  Not having the st_within simplifies the query, doesn't need a union, and makes it faster.

Answer (score 4):

What would happen if you omit the `"st_multi(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom))"` part?

Doesn't the below query mean the same thing without it? I ran it on the data you provided.

```
INSERT INTO parcel_jurisdictions(parcel_gid,jurisdiction_gid,isect_geom)
  SELECT
    a.orig_gid parcel_gid,
    b.orig_gid jurisdiction_gid,
    a.geom
  FROM
    valid_parcels a, valid_jurisdictions b
  WHERE
    st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom);
```

**Configuration**

```
Processor: AMD Athlon II X4 635 2.9 GHz 
Memory: 4 GB
Platform: Windows 7 Professional
Potgres Version: 8.4
Postgis Version: "POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" GEOS="3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.9.1, released 2012/05/15" LIBXML="2.7.8" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"
```

**Analyze Results**

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..7505.18 rows=217489 width=1580) (actual time=1.994..248405.616 rows=329150 loops=1)"
"  Join Filter: _st_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on valid_jurisdictions b  (cost=0.00..37.25 rows=525 width=22621) (actual time=0.054..1.732 rows=525 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using valid_parcels_index on valid_parcels a  (cost=0.00..11.63 rows=2 width=1576) (actual time=0.068..6.423 rows=1366 loops=525)"
"        Index Cond: (a.geom && b.geom)"
"Total runtime: 280087.497 ms"
```

Comment: No, he wants the resultant intersection polygons, but your query very nicely demonstrates that all the pain is in the intersection generation, not in the binary true/false testing part of the query. And that's quite expected, since the true/false code is highly optimized while the intersection generation is not.