# PostGIS Union Between Two Tables, Preserving Attributes

Tags: postgis, union

I'm trying to union US State level upper- and lower-level government boundaries in such a way that generates one PostGIS table with both the upper and lower level names for each shape.

In my example below, `U` is a dataset and has a column with rows `UA` and `UB`. `L` is another dataset and has `LA`, `LB`, and `LC`. When I union the shapes together I should get the same shapes as `L` but the new, unioned dataset has both data columns.

[image]

**Edit**: My example image above is pretty crummy. The answers so far have been related to querying the data assuming the geometry is available. This is important but is skipping the more confusing part of my question. A better example:

[image]

The yellow shape is from `U`, the orange shape is from `L`. Notice that they overlap but some pieces of the polygons aren't contained completely inside another shape (like in my example where `LB` and `LC` are completely within `UB`).

The question I was trying to ask is about correctly chopping the two layers so the resulting data set has no overlaps. See for example [this mailing list post](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/2009-October/024911.html) that gets close but doesn't quite work.

Comment: Side comment: calling this a "union", which is the ESRI term for the operation will be confusing to PostGIS people, since the ST_Union function does the opposite of this (which ESRI calls "dissolve") and melts features together. A vendor-neutral term might be "overlay".

Comment: I think my question is very similar to [this one](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83/separate-polygons-based-on-intersection-using-postgis) that was already asked and fairly well answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing your column names, this is my best guess. (I have not had a chance to test, so it may not be exactly right.)  Hopefully you can suss out the column names I used.  Assuming L is a subset of U:

```
SELECT l.id AS l_id, u.ab AS uab, l.abc AS labc, ST_Intersection(u.geom, l.geom) AS geom
  FROM u, l
  WHERE ST_Intersects(ST_PointOnSurface(l.geom), u.geom);
```

Comment: This is correct, see also http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31562/457 for a performance tweak on this approach.

Comment: This is perfect once I have the shapes generated, but first I need to build the unioned shapes. My example drawing isn't the greatest at demonstrating this, but I need to cut the geometries so there are no overlaps, first.

Comment: I think you didn't read the SQL closely enough, it's generating new shapes that consist of just the shared areas. The output of this query has no overlapping features.

Comment: You're absolutely right Paul -- I think I meant to comment on Nicklas's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how clean and consistent your data is. If you can assume that the centroid of table L can be found inside the matching polygon in table U you can write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM U INNER JOIN L ON ST_Intersects(L.Centroid(geom),U.geom);
```

Then you should get what you want. If you use the whole geometry instead of the centroid of L you will get a lot of strange matches.

HTH

Nicklas

Comment: Note that Centroid function does not guarantee a point that lies within the polygon. ST_PointOnSurface does.

Comment: @Scro you are absolutely right. Miss from me.