# Inserting union of two tables into another table using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a research project. I have two tables, one of a polygon that represents a severe weather risk area, one that represents the US. I want to merge them into one output polygon. I am stuck with the syntax of how to do this.

`spc` is the table of the risk area, `simple_us` is the us. I want to output the union of these two table into the geometry column of a new table called `spc_clip`.

My current command is:

```
INSERT INTO spc_clip (geom) VALUES (ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom)), spc as a, simple_us as b;
```

As it sits now I get a syntax error at spc when I run the command.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Next I want to export the geometry of the union to a JSON. I am not sure how to do this. I cannot test this line until I get the above union done.

```
SELECT row_to_json(t) FROM (SELECT name,geom FROM spc_clip) t;
```

NOTE: name is already in the table and works fine. I am just struggling with the join and the json export.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53883/postgis-union-between-two-tables-preserving-attributes

Comment: Your initial problem is of syntax.  You have the `geom` referenced with the destination table.  In the values section, however, you are listing 3 different columns.  The references to the `spc as a`, and `simple_us as b` should be in a subquery to the `ST_Union command.  This is in addition to the information that @Mapperz provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead your INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO spc_clip (geom)
  SELECT (ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom))
  FROM spc as a, simple_us as b;
```