# PostGIS Join Queries results in Missing MultiPolygons

Tags: postgis

I'm trying to join two PostGIS table, one of [DMAs](http://bl.ocks.org/simzou/6459889) and another of [states](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2015/STATE/).

After getting some [help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/165154/separating-overlapping-dmas-by-state-using-postgis), I ran this query:

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS
     SELECT nextval('polyseq_1') AS id, 
     b.name AS state_name, 
a.dma_1 AS dma_1, 
CASE WHEN ST_Within(a.geom, b.geom) 
    THEN a.geom 
     ELSE ST_MULTI(ST_INTERSECTION(a.geom,b.geom)) end AS geom 
FROM us_states b 
JOIN us_dma a ON ST_INTERSECTS(a.geom, b.geom)
```

However, the results I get have some gaps, for instance, it looks like the Dallas DMA in Texas is completely missing. I'm not familiar with PostGIS but I am unable to figure why the query will cause polygons to be missing. A picture is below:

[image: Result of query]

Comment: My initial thought would be to check those particular polygons for any inconsistencies.  For example, are there loops or something in the polygons that cause them to error?

Comment: @GetSpatial, not that I know of. The Dallas DMA looks pretty normal to me

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change your ST_Within(a.geom,b.geom) to ST_CoveredBy(a.geom, b.geom).  If a.geom shares a border with b.geom, then ST_Within will return false, but ST_CoveredBy will return true.

Still the best article explaining this subtlety is this - http://lin-ear-th-inking.blogspot.com/2007/06/subtleties-of-ogc-covers-spatial.html

Comment: I tried using ```St_CoveredBy``` and the results still ended up being exactly the same. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you verify they are valid with ST_IsValid?  If they are not a lot of functions such as ST_Intersects, ST_CoveredBy will just return false.