# What is the PostGIS equivalent of ArcGIS "Intersect" tool?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, postgis

I am looking for the PostGIS ST_*function* that will give me the same results as running the ArcGIS Analyis-> Overlays-> [Intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000p000000) on two polygons.

Answer (score 2):

What your looking for is [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html).

> ST_Intersection — (T) Returns a geometry that represents the shared portion of geomA and geomB. The geography implementation does a transform to geometry to do the intersection and then transform back to WGS84.

```
geometry ST_Intersection( geometry geomA , geometry geomB );
```

You can see a query that implements it in [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31310/acquiring-arcgis-like-speed-in-postgis) question (down at the bottom).