# PostGIS (hopefully faster) alternative to v.overlay with or condition from GRASS

Tags: postgis, grass-gis

I have two distinct tables, one called rpg(id, code_culture, geom --polygons) and the other called ia(id, classe, geom --also polygons)
Like this :

[image: capture]

How should I proceed to get a single table with a single geometry while retaining the two attributes and ids like result(id_rp, id_ia, classe, code_culture, geom)?

Edit:

So far, I managed to do this :

[image]

With that query, adapted from some material here on stackex but it missed all the geom from ia that's not intersected by rpg but when they do, it's all good with both geom creating new polygons when intersected :

```
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT 
    ia.id AS ia_id, rpg.id AS rpg_id
    , ST_Multi(ST_Intersection(ia.geom, rpg.geom)) AS geom
FROM ia, rpg
WHERE ST_Intersects(ia.geom, rpg.geom) AND NOT ST_Within(ia.geom, rpg.geom)

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ia.id AS ia_id, rpg.id AS rpg_id
    , ia.geom AS geom
FROM ia, rpg
WHERE ST_Within(ia.geom, rpg.geom)
)
    SELECT ia_id, rpg_id, (ST_Dump(geom)).geom::geometry(Polygon, 2154) AS geom 
    FROM cte1;
```

Edit 2 with solution :

WITH poly_a AS (
SELECT id, NULL AS code_cultu, classe, geom FROM ref_autres.cosia_small_singlepoly
)
,poly_b AS (
SELECT id, code_cultu, NULL AS classe, geom FROM ref_autres.rpg_small_singlepoly
)
,lines AS (
SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) AS geom FROM poly_a
UNION ALL
SELECT ST_Boundary(geom) AS geom FROM poly_b
)
,noded_lines AS ( SELECT ST_Union(geom) AS geom FROM lines )
,resultants AS (
SELECT geom, ST_PointOnSurface(geom) AS pip
FROM St_Dump(
(SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) AS geom FROM noded_lines ))
)
SELECT a.id AS ida, b.id AS idb, a.classe, b.code_cultu, r.geom
FROM resultants r
LEFT JOIN poly_a a ON ST_Contains(a.geom, r.pip)
LEFT JOIN poly_b b ON ST_Contains(b.geom, r.pip)
WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL OR b.id IS NOT NULL;

[image]

Comment: QGIS has a multitude of processing tools that can help you to achieve that. If you can use it.

Comment: I can and I did (I have a result from GRASS) but I still would like to learn how to do this one in sql :)

Comment: Check out the spatial joins in this tutorial: https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/

Comment: Make sure you got [spatial indexes](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html) on both tables, or the queries will be slow. Your output goal is the equivalent of a QGIS [Union](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoroverlay.html#union) operation?

Comment: Yes, if the qgis union is like the GRASS overlay with or condition (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass83/manuals/v.overlay.html) And yes I added the spatial indexes when importing to postgis via qgis :)

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/401245/getting-the-composite-of-two-polygon-layers

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I got a working query, quite expensive in time but I'm gonna compare against the same ops in GRASS on the full datasets ! 
I'm editing the initial post with the answer :)