# Algorithm to find the polygon ID where a point belongs to

Tags: postgis, algorithm

I am wondering what is the simplest way to perform a look up of polygon Id based on the point location.

Input: a point with coordinates, a table of polygons

Output: the polygon Id where a point is located.

I am thinking to preload the polygon table into PostGIS (The size is about 220,000 entries). What is the best way to process all these data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ST_Contains](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_Contains.html) operator in PostGIS does Point-in-Polygon analyses just fine. You may also be interested in this question about improving the performance of similar queries:
  [Looking for fastest solution for Point in Polygon analysis of 200 million points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24554/looking-for-fastest-solution-for-point-in-polygon-analysis-of-200-million-points)